# stopping serialization of some class types in inheritance tree in java

Tags: java, inheritance, serialization

I have an inheritance tree where
 `Class A implements Serializable{}`
`Class B extends A{}` and `Class C extends B{}` and so on upto `class Z extends Y{}`

**According to Serialization:**

"Since `Class A` implements `Serializable`, all the  subclasses upto `Z` become 'Serializable'". And when we try to serialize object of `Z`, all the super class objects will be serialized.
**Question:**

How can i avoid object of `Class C` getting serialized, when i am serializing object of `Z Class`?

Comment: With `Serializable` you can't choose to serialize fields some times and not others. You can use the `transient` modifier to mark a field so that it doesn't get serialized.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Do we have any other alternative ?

Comment: Don't use Java serialization, use another format, like XML or JSON.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Can we override the functionality with `writeObject()`  and `readObject()` in the classes which we don't want to be serialized.?

Comment: I think that if it makes sense to serialize B but not C, then that's an indication that C probably shouldn't be a subclass of B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, if C is in the superclass chain of Z, and you *want* to serialize Z, then C will also be serialized. You can avoid or work around this using one of the following techniques:

**Rearrange the class hierarchy.**

That is, make C no longer a superclass of Z. Presumably you don't want to do this, but it might be reasonable to consider given the goal of not serializing C.

**Control the fields of C that are serialized.**

You can mark as `transient` the fields of C that aren't serialized. Perhaps better is to declare a `serialPersistentFields` array in C, possibly empty, containing the names of fields of C that are to be serialized. This might be easier or more maintainable than marking fields you don't want serialized as `transient`. Note that C is still serialized, but the serialization of its fields can be omitted.

**Provide a custom serialization format for C.**

That is, use `readObject` and `writeObject` methods. If you don't call `defaultWriteObject` from your `writeObject` method, then none of the automatic field serialization of C will occur. Similarly, don't call `defaultReadObject` from within your `readObject` method. Note that, as above, this still serializes C itself, but avoids serializing some or all of its fields.

**Provide a serialization proxy for Z.**

Provide a `writeReplace` method for Z. The `writeReplace` method arranges things so that when somebody requests to serialize Z, a *different* object (called ZProxy for example) is serialized instead. Have your `writeReplace` method construct a ZProxy instance containing exactly the data from Z you want serialized, and return that ZProxy instance. That instnace will be serialized in place of the Z instance. ZProxy doesn't have to be in the same class hierarchy as Z; it can be completely unrelated. When a ZProxy instance is deserialized, make sure that ZProxy has a `readResolve` method that constructs a Z instance from the data in the ZProxy and returns the Z instance instead.

See Bloch, *Effective Java*, Item 78 for further information about serialization proxies.

You might also want to provide a Z.readObject method that throws an exception, to prevent somebody from forging a serialized bytestream that purports to contain a serialized instance of Z and then deserializing that. This enforces the constraint that only ZProxy instances appear in the serialized byte stream, and never actual Z instances.